# How do you disabled Apex:OutputField?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

Hi I want the code below to be a read-only. If I changed it to outputText, the user won't be able to click the name of the account and view the account. Is there a way I can remove the pencil from the outputField?

```
   <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.AccountId}" ></apex:outputField>
```

Comment: Did you find the solution

Answer (score 0):

Post more code? By default outputField should be enough, field shouldn't be editable.

Any chance you have `<apex:inlineEditSupport>` somewhere on the page? See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_inline_editing.htm for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I used inlineEditSupport and if you want to disabled a specific field. Just use this.

```
   <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.AccountId}"><apex:inlineEditSupport disabled="true"/></apex:outputField>
```